# What letter am I?

Tags: cipher, visual

I am representing a specific letter... what letter am I?

[image: image puzzle]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the letter is

> the Greek letter **pi** ($ \pi $)

The image depicts

> a set of concentric ovals being divided into 10 sectors. This suggests that we can assign each sector a unique digit from 0-9.

If we

> let the sector containing the red shaded area equal the digit 0, and assign sectors with ascending digits going clockwise from that area,

then the gray shaded areas represent

> the digits 31415926..., which happen to be the first few digits in the decimal representation of $ \pi $. This is a plausible answer since $ \pi $ is a letter in the Greek alphabet.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, it's π :). Also, the dot in the first shaded section(3) is supposed to be read as "3 dot" and the three dots in the last shaded section(6) is suppose to be "6 dot dot dot"